# The greatest prophet after Moses

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, nevua-prophecy, eliyahu-hanavi, rav-yaakov-emden

[R. Jacob Emden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Emden), in his comments to Eruvin 43a, refers to [Elijah the Prophet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah) as the greatest prophet after [Moses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses):

> אליהו הנביא הגדול בנביאים אחרי משרע"ה

That Moses was the greatest prophet is hardly controversial. It is attested to in Scripture and enshrined into fundamental Jewish theology by Maimonides.

Elijah is probably the most famous prophet in Judaism. This is probably due to his involvement, according to various traditions, in Jewish life throughout the millenia – attending circumcisions, drinking wine from every house on Passover Eve, hanging out with some of the Sages in the Talmud as well as the Hasidic masters, etc.

The question is, though, is there anything to indicate that he was actually the greatest prophet after Moses? Whence did R. Emden know this?

In fact, perusal of some other parts of rabbinic literature leads to a different conclusion. [R. David Kimchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kimhi), in his commentary to Psalms 99:6 writes that [Samuel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel) was possibly the greatest prophet after Moses, and in his commentary to
Jeremiah he states this definitively and cites several verses that could be indicative of this:

**Psalms 99:6**

> וזכר שמואל לפי שהיה ממשפחת משה ואהרן ונביא כמו הם ואפשר שהיה גדול
>   בנבואה משאר הנביאים אחר משה, וכן אמר אם יעמוד משה ושמואל לפני

**Jeremiah 15:1**

> והגדול שבנביאים אחר משה רבינו היה שמואל וכן אמר משה ואהרן בכהניו
>   ושמואל בקוראי שמו ונאמר כי נאמן שמואל לנביא לה' ונאמר ולא הפיל מכל
>   דבריו ארצה

R. Kimchi's ranking is perhaps supported by the [Midrash Tanchuma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhuma) which refers to Samuel as "Master/Teacher of all the prophets":

**Leviticus Chapter 21**

> שמואל [רבן] של כל הנביאים

Beyond this, though, are there any authoritative sources that discuss prophet rankings (the earlier the better)? Either in support of, or contravening, R. Emden's view or R. Kimchi's view?

---

Interestingly, R. Emden's statement has been edited out of most editions of the Talmud. The only edition I was able to find it in was the Nehardea Talmud. Below is an image showing the Nehardea edition with the statement of Elijah's rank, followed by an image showing the Oz V'hadar edition with the part about Elijah's rank missing. That many of R. Emden's Talmudic comments have been censored/edited/concealed has already been pointed out by [R. Jacob J. Schachter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_J._Schacter) in his dissertation on R. Emden:

**Jacob Emden: Life and Major Works Chapter 2 Note 60**

> These novellae differ from Emden's Hagahot 'al ha-Shas printed in the
>   back of the standard Vilna edition of the Talmud. Those comments
>   represent a partial transcription of Emden's marginalia on his
>   personal copy of the Talmud, presently found in the Jewish National
>   and University Library of the Hebrew Universit in Jerusalem (Heb
>   4<sup>o</sup> 181). See Y. Yoel, "'Osef Kitvei-Yad bi-Bet Dfus Rom,"
>   KS XIII (1937), 521-522. Even a cursory comparative study indicates
>   that not everything written by Emden in the margins of his private
>   books was included in the Vilna edition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pardon, but you seem to have offered potential answers to your own question.

Comment: @ezra How so? How so?

Comment: What are your criteria for measuring the greatness of a prophet?

Comment: @Jasper I don't know.

Comment: Tanchuma [Korach 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma,_Korach.5.1) and Tanchuma Yashan [Korach 12](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma_Buber,_Korach.12.1) says Shmuel was equivalent to Moshe and Aharon,  coming from the verse in Psalms you brought.

Comment: Even if someone was _historically_ the second greatest prophet, there could still be someone in the future who will overtake him.  As opposed to Moshe who will keep his title forever.

Answer (score 8):

The Yerushalmi (Eiruvin 5:1, 31a) states that Elijah was טירונין לנביאים. The Korban Ha-Eidah defines this as גדול שבנביאים, and cites the Aruch who explains that this means he was the authority of the prophets (ענין שררה--see also [here](http://www.babynamewizard.com/baby-name/boy/tyron)). [The P'nei Moshe, however, seems to understand the word as related to "tyro," i.e., a beginner.] It would seem that R. Yaakov Emden probably understood the Yerushalmi in accordance with the Korban Ha-Eidah. The Yalkut Shimoni, Melachim 209, gives a long list of parallels between Moses and Elijah, which strengthens the case for Elijah as the greatest prophet following Moses:

> זהו שאמר הכתוב ובנביא העלה ה' את ישראל ממצרים ובנביא נשמר, ובנביא העלה
>   ה' זה משה, ובנביא נשמר זה אליהו ז"ל, אתה מוצא שני נביאים עמדו לישראל
>   משבטו של לוי משה ראשון ואליהו אחרון ושניהם גואלים את ישראל בשליחות,
>   משה גאלם ממצרים ועתה לכה ואשלחך אל פרעה, ואליהו לעתיד לבא הנה אנכי
>   שולח לכם את אליה הנביא, משה גאלם ממצרים תחלה עוד לא חזרו ונשתעבדו
>   במצרים ואליהו כשיגאל אותם מן הרביעית עוד אינם חוזרים ומשתעבדים אלא
>   תשועת עולמים, ואתה מוצא שמשה ואליהו שוים זה לזה לכל דבר משה נביא
>   ואליהו נביא, משה נקרא איש האלהים ואליהו נקרא איש האלהים, משה עלה למעלה
>   ואליהו עלה למעלה שנאמר ויהי בהעלות ה' את אליהו, משה הרג את המצרי
>   ואליהו הרג את חיאל שנאמר ויאשם בבעל וימת, משה נתכלכל על ידי אשה שנאמר
>   קראן לו ויאכל לחם ואליהו נתכלכל על ידי הצרפית שנאמר לקחי נא לי פת לחם
>   משה ברח מפני פרעה ואליהו ברח מפני איזבל, משה ברח ובא לבאר ואליהו ברח
>   ובא לבאר שנאמר ויבא באר שבע, משה אמר אם כמות כל אדם ימותון אלה ואליהו
>   חי ה' וגו' אם יהיה וגו' טל ומטר, במשה ויעבר ה' על פניו ובאליהו והנה ה'
>   עובר, במשה וישמע את הקול ובאליהו והנה אליו קול, משה כנס את ישראל לפני
>   הר סיני ואליהו כנסם להר הכרמל. משה בער עובדי ע"ז שנאמר שימו איש חרבו
>   על ירכו ואליהו בער עובדי ע"ז ותפש נביאי הבעל ושחטם, משה קנא מי לה' אלי
>   ואליהו קנא שנאמר ויאמר אליהו לכל העם גשו נא אלי, משה נטמן במערה שנאמר
>   ושמתיך בנקרת הצור ואליהו נטמן במערה שנאמר ויבא שם אל המערה וילן שם.
>   משה ויבא אל הר האלהים, ואליהו (ויבא) [וילך] וגו' עד הר האלהים, משה בא
>   למדבר ואליהו בא למדבר מדברה דמשק, משה השיח עמו על ידי מלאך שנאמר וירא
>   מלאך ה' אליו ואליהו והנה זה מלאך, משה ארבעים יום וארבעים לילה לא אכל
>   ואליהו וילך בכח האכילה ההיא ארבעים יום, משה התפלל על ישראל שנאמר אל
>   תשחת עמך ואליהו התפלל שנאמר ענני ה' ענני, משה תפש זכות אבות שנאמר זכור
>   לאברהם ואליהו שתים עשרה מצבה לאמר ישראל יהיה שמך, משה קבלו ישראל על
>   ידו אהבתו של מקום שנאמר כל אשר דבר ה' נעשה ונשמע ואליהו קבלו על ידו
>   ואמרו ה' הוא האלהים, משה עשה משכן כבית סאתים זרע וכן אליהו, משה כשבנה
>   את המזבח בנה אותו י"ב אבנים למספר בני ישראל וכן אליהו ויקח אליהו שתים
>   עשרה אבנים וגו'. חי ה' וגו' אשר עמדתי לפניו, ר' ברכיה בר' חלבו בשם ר'
>   שמואל בר רב יצחק וכי לפני שכינה הוא עומד אלא כל זמן שהיה עומד לפני
>   אחיה השילוני כאלו עומד לפני השכינה. אם יהיה טל ומטר י' רעבון וכו'
>   (כתוב ברמז קנ"ד):

Comment: This is precisely the type of answer I am looking for.

Comment: Couldn't this mean he was the greatest/leader of the prophets **of his time**?

Comment: The Korban HaEidah to Yerushalmi Eruvin 5:1, 31a does not understand טירונין to be ‘despotic ruler’ of the prophets (like אין הקב״ה בא בטירוניא). He understands it to mean like it is used with Moshe Rabbeinu in Shemot Rabbah 3:1. That Eliyahu was at the beginning of his days as a prophet, like the posuk cited (1 Kings 17:1). Rather, he is juxtaposing the seemingly contrary statements to develop the question which the text of the Shas answers. While standing and serving before his teacher it was like standing before the Shechina.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Who said anything about a despotic ruler? What would that even mean in this context?

Comment: And the citation that Korban HaEidah makes to the Aruch is the 3rd listing of the root (טרן) and says it is the concept of (שרי׳) as it is used in Yerushalmi Terumot 8, 44a at the bottom (מישרי מתרתר), which means ‘to begin’.

Comment: @wfb Korban HaEidah translates an abbreviation (שרי׳) from the Aruch as שררה which is ruling with authority, being despotic. Trying to associate שררה to טרוניא. But the abbreviation used in the Aruch doesn’t mean שררה. It is from the verb root שרי which means ‘to begin’ as used in Yerushalmi Terumot cited in my previous comment. That is why the Aruch points to its usage in connection with Eliyahu in 1 Kings 17:1  cited in Yerushalmi Eruvin 5:1, 31a.

Comment: @YaacovDeane 1. Authority does not equal "despotic." 2. The Aruch does define the word as connected to טרוניא, as well as citing the midrash about Moshe. See http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48231&st=&pgnum=87

Comment: @wfb There are many terms that can be translated as authority. That’s true. But טרוניא, as it is used in Torah has the connotation of despotic authority & rule. Eliyahu as Navi is an actual agent of G-d. If he departs from that relationship, he loses the status of prophet & capability. That means he must follow in G-d’s ways, for example (אין הקב״ה בא בטירוניא).

Comment: @wfb FYI, the link you have is not the actual Aruch. It’s something compiled and edited by someone else at a much later date. To assess the statements of the Korban HaEidah about the Aruch, you should be looking at what the author of the Aruch actually wrote, not the edited later edition.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The word here is not טרוניא. Also in the Yerushalmi I have seen it is not written as an abbreviation but as follows: טירונין. לשון שררה כ"פ הערוך. I incorporated the P'nei Moshe, who gives something closer to your interpretation, into my answer. However, it seems R. Yaakov Emden probably understood the Yerushalmi as did the Korban Ha-Eidah.

Comment: see also R. Matisyahu Strashun on the Midrash https://books.google.com/books?id=TZ4tAAAAYAAJ&lpg=RA1-PA77&ots=t4t4M-uHFn&dq=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94&pg=RA1-PA77#v=onepage&q=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94&f=false

Comment: and R. Avraham Krochmal https://books.google.com/books?id=uNctAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PT20&ots=d364qfzfjK&dq=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94&pg=PT20#v=onepage&q=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94&f=false

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your two part quest, "Is there anything to indicate that he (meaning Eliyahu) was actually the greatest prophet after Moses? Whence did R. Emden know this?"

As you say, Moshe is the greatest of the prophets (אדון כל הנביאים) like is stated in Sefer Tzeidah l'Derech at the end in the laws relating to redemption and Moshiach.

Considering that Rabbi Emden was an expert in both the revealed parts of Torah and the concealed parts of Torah, it wouldn't be difficult to imagine that he was familiar with [Sefer Brit Menucha by Rabbi Avraham of Rimon](https://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10278&strReferer=search&PPGR=0) and which is attributed to Rav Chamaui Gaon.

[In the beginning of that book](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44425&st=&pgnum=8), he explains a concept found in Isaiah 43:7 which says:

> כל הנקרא בשמי גו׳

saying that all prophecy comes to us via/through these three angels represented by the word *Shemi*. שמ״י which stands for the names of the angels assigned as agents for prophecy.

Those three angels manifest in this world as Moshe Rabbeinu (**מ**טטרון **ש**ר **ה**פנים מש״ה), Eliyahu HaNavi (יהואל, אליה״ו) and Shmuel HaNavi (שמועאל, שמוא״ל).

In the order of the Rosh Teivot found in Isaiah, it places Moshe Rabbeinu in the center being escorted by both Shmuel and Elihau. And this is in keeping with the principle found in Brachot 43b that a Talmid Chacham (like Moshe Rabbeinu) should be escorted by two disciples (like Shmuel HaNavi and Eliyahu HaNavi) when traveling.

In the context of the discussion in Brit Menucha, it corresponds to the general arrangement called *the three pillars* of Chesed, Gevurah and Tiferet, which also correspond to the three Avot, Avraham (Chesed), Yitzchok (Gevurah) and Yaacov (Tiferet). Tiferet, which is the intermediate connecting link between the two extremes, comprises them both and is the greatest of the three. Chesed and Gevurah are escorts, so to speak to Tiferet, and are equal but opposite to each other.

Eliyahu is generally associated with Gevurah, which would mean that Shmuel corresponds to Chesed, which is also called *Gedolah*.

So linguistically Rabbi Emden would seem to referring to Eliyahu in the context of being a *Gibbor*, one who overcomes and overturns his opponent. And that appears to be his explanation in the first of the photographed images in your question.

Comment: Does this actually say that Eliyahu was the second-to-greatest?

Comment: @Alex I don't have the sefer in front of me right now, but as memory serves, it portrays that like with Moshe, Metatron is the leader and the other two angels, who correspond to Shmuel and Eliyahu, are equal status escorts. It's not a surprise. It would also be consistent with the general arrangement of the 3 pillars of Chesed, Gevurah and Tiferet. The central pillar encompasses the other 2 and serves as an intermediate connecting link. If you are looking for a discussion of the concept, check out the discussion of 'chatzotzrot' by the Maggid of Mezeritch.